# Uploaded file not saving in folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have tried everything but still i cant figure out why the uploaded file is not saving anywhere.....
My HTML CODE:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='generate_xml.php' method='POST'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter Remote ID :</td> <td> <input type='text' name='remote' required /></td><br />       </tr><tr>
<td>Enter Alter_id :    </td><td> <input type='text' name='alter' required/></td> <br />     </tr><tr>
<td>Enter Master ID :    </td><td><input type='text' name='master' required/> </td><br /></tr><tr>
<td>Enter Vch ID :      </td><td> <input type='text' name='vch' required/> </td><br /></tr><tr>
<td>Enter Date Account : </td><td><input type='text' name='date' required/> </td><br /></tr><tr>
<td>Choose a file to upload: <input name='uploadedfile' type='file' /></td><br /></tr>

<tr><td>
<input type='submit' value='submit' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here's my Code

```
if(! empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))
    {
        $this->config->load('je_settings',TRUE);
        $tally_folder_path = $this->config->item('tally_folder_path');
        $template_file_path = FCPATH;
        $tally_folder_path="/home/torrez/Public/";
        $file_type = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
        $allowed = array('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values');
        if( ! empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) && in_array($file_type, $allowed))
        {
            $tally_src_file = $tally_folder_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']      ['name']);
            $name = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($name, $tally_folder_path);
        }
        else
        {
            die("No file specified or Format not supported");
        }
```

Please help!!!

Comment: give folder 0777 permission and check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include src file path instead of file file path....

```
$tally_src_file = $tally_folder_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $tally_src_file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change name to `tmp_name` and `$_FILES['uploadedfile']`

```
$name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: it seems that it might be $_FILES['uploadedfile'] and not $_FILES['file'], but otherwise the idea is valid, you need to use the temporary path to the file

Comment: and also: without basename because that's a full path to your temporary directory

Comment: @user3886699 try not using basename on your script

Comment: @user3886699 that's might be because you seem to be writing to a path that is a directory. You need to provide the entire path to the final file. So something like `$tally_folder_path . 'test.csv'` (you might need to also add a slash depending on what you have in that variable

Comment: /home/name/Public/neew.csv" this is what i get while dumping tally_src_file... I am sure the path is correct...

Comment: @user3886699 in that case most of the time this is a permissions related issue

Comment: after the upload it will generate a new file in that folder itself.....So a new empty file is created in the folder... Since uploaded file is not saving there it cant get the contents so it generating an empty file in that folder... so i dont think permission is not a problem...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this this might help you

your code is:

```
 $file_type = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
 $allowed = array('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values');
```

there will be problem with allowed type array
 you define it like

```
$allowed = array('csv','txt','jpg');
```

Remember to give 777 permission to the folder to which you uploading files.
I think then it will work.

as Its recommended to not use `$_FILES['file']['type']`
in place of that you can use

```
$ext =  filetype ( string $filename );
```

it return extension of file.

can refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I think there is some problem with file extension.
So, suggest you to check with it.

Comment: In form You  already have the enctype="multipart/form-data" which is very important to have on the form.
Please check with php.ini once
There you should have:

file_uploads = On; sounds like you already did this
post_max_size = 8M; change this higher if needed
upload_max_file_size = 8M; change this higher if needed
Remember to restart Apache after you made the php.ini changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to used the codeigniter uploading library.
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

-> Make sure that the path you are uploading is real and writable
-> Dump your `$_FILES` and see if it displays the right value and array index

Here is my sample code when uploading:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

        $config['upload_path'] = $path = 'Your Path'; //MAKES SURE THIS PATH IS WRITABLE AND A REAL PATH
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['remove_spaces']  = true;
        $config['overwrite']  = true;
        $config['encrypt_name']  = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            //error in upload
            var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else
        {
            //success upload
            var_dump($this->upload->data());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your codes (HTML FORM) and can you dump us the value of `$tally_folder_path`.

One thing more, make sure when you run it will pass through the `move_uploaded_file()` method. Make a `die()` function before it.